# How do I collect field values of a submitted webform?

Tags: 7, rules, webforms, emails, tokens

I'm trying to integrate a Mailchimp mailing list into Drupal. The Mailchimp list requires:

- First Name
- Last Name
- E-Mail

The client already has a list in this format so ideally I need to collect this data in Drupal.

I want to have a newsletter block that collects the email address and forwards a user to another page that has the full newsletter sign up with first name last name and the email but pre filled out.

I know I'm going to need [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform). But how can I collect the value of the webform field and use it again as a token later?

**Note**:  I am using this within the Drupal setup, but the list requires three fields of data (first/lastname/email). I want to have a block that initially collects the email and forwards them to the full newsletter signup page. I have the webform and rules working to direct the user from the page with the block to the signup page, but I need to find out how to create a custom token from the field.

Comment: Did you know there's a [MailChimp module](http://drupal.org/project/mailchimp)?

Comment: Yes i am using it within the drupal setup, but the list requires three fields of data first/lastname/email

I want to have a block that initially collects the email and forwards them to the full newsletter signup page, i have the webform and rules working to direct the user from the page with the block to the signup page but i need to find out how to create a custom token from the field

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Webform Mailchimp](http://drupal.org/project/webform_mailchimp) , different approach but may be of use

> Provides a webform component that lets users subscribe to a Mailchimp
>   newsletter as they submit a webform.

Answer (score 0):

You do have access to all ***labels*** and all ***values*** of any field of a webform, ie:

- `[data:MachineFieldName-title]` contains the **Label** of a field with machine name MachineFieldName.
- `[data:MachineFieldName-value]` contains the **Value** of a field with machine name MachineFieldName

So in your case, you might be able to get it to work using something like `[data:email-id]` (assuming that's what corresponds to the "*email field*" in your case).

For way more details on this, and a prototype rule about this, refer to the answer to "[How to create a node from a Webform using rules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199821/how-to-create-a-node-from-a-webform-using-rules/199825#199825)":

- the *1st attempt* relates to using "Entity has field" (which doesn't work for [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform))
- the *2nd attempt* explains what to do in case of [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform).

Even though the above is a good start, it may not be sufficient to achieve your goal (= "*... how can I collect the value of the webform field and use it again as a token later ...*", as in your question).
However, you can use a technique similar to what is described in [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/191977/39516) to "[How to do a data comparison to submitted webform data when using the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/191953/39516)". For short:

- Add an extra Rules Action to `Add a variable`, with a value assigned to it equal to your `[data:EmailField-value-raw]` (and with an appropriate data type). I'm assuming your eMail field in your webform has a machine name like `EmailField` (adapt to fit your machine name).
- In your subsequent Rules Actions you can refer to the value of this variable you just added (that's the clue!).

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.

Answer (score 0):

I dedicate a blogpost on how to add a custom `WebformSubmitHandler` to process the data. Read about it here: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/how-create-mailchimp-subscription-drupal-8-webform-module